# Setting up keyboard shortcuts to perform a terminal command

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

I'd like to perform certain actions by keyboard shortcut on Linux Mint 17.3. Specifically, I'd like to execute commands

`expressvpn connect` (connecting to my VPN provider)

and

`xsel -b|xsel -bi` (strips formatting from whatever text is copied to clipboard)

Both commands work fine when I open Terminal and type them in. But when I try to work them into shortcuts in the Keyboard settings, no luck. I've tried

```
gnome-terminal -e "xsel -b|xsel -bi"
```

and

```
gnome-terminal -e "expressvpn connect"
```

to no avail. These won't work when typed to Terminal, either.

I understand from previous answers that `-e` doesn't like spaces; so how do I get these commands to work?

Comment: do you have to do this with a a keyboard shortcut (in Keyboard settings), or would a shell alias be acceptable?

Comment: I'm more than open for any suggestions on how to achieve the goals :). 

Sorry to say but my Linux expertise is minimal and my command line expertise tends to date from the good old days of MS-DOS 4.0 :).

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Put the commands you want to run in individual scripts and then create keyboard shortcuts to run the scripts. The clipboard formatting example would look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
xsel -b|xsel -bi
```

If you save that file in ~/scripts/strip-format.sh you'll need to give it executable permissions with `chmod +x ~/scripts/strip-format.sh` and then add your custom shortcut. Make sure you use the full path to the script. In the screenshot replace `$USER` with your username.

[image]

After you add the shortcut give it a keyboard combo and it should run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You could make aliases for these instead of keyboard shortcuts. On the assumption that you are using the default shell (bash), edit your ~/.bash_profile and add these lines:

```
alias sf='xsel -b | xsel -bi'
alias vpn='expressvpn connect'
```

where you can change the names from 'sf' and 'vpn' to whatever you want. Run `. ~/.bash_profile` in a terminal window (or copy/paste the same alias lines into the shell window directly) to begin using them.